# TLClientNode connection

Tags: riscv, chisel

I need to instantiate the recent version of the ICache in ROCKET-CHIP project stand-alone. I was able to test this instantiation using 6 months old version. However, I am facing troubles with its 'mem' port in the recent version:

```
val node = TLClientNode(TLClientParameters(sourceId = IdRange(0,1)))
.....
val mem = outer.node.bundleOut
```

According to my understanding, ROCKET-CHIP project started to use special type of nodes where both SOURCE and SINK nodes shall be connected on a bar using 'TLXbar' class. I tried to follow the code in http://stackissue.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip/tilelink2-245.html but it seem obsolete. Can anyone point to me how can I connect this port?

Answer (score 2):

Recently I successfully created a trivial TileLink2 node (just passing input to output with some masks) and inserted it between `l1backend.node` and `TileNetwork.masterNodes.head`. So I think my experience might be helpful.

Rocket-chip's `diplomacy` package extends chisel's `Module` hierarchy. It mainly consists two parts: `LazyModule` and `LazyModuleImp`, where `LazyModuleImp` is the real `Module` in chisel world.

Nodes are always created in `LazyModule`, while `node.bundleIn/Out` should be referenced inside `LazyModuleImpl`. We should use nodes in `LazyModule` to interconnect with each other by `:=`.

Another thing that might be helpful is that inside `LazyModuleImp` we can only reference `bundleIn/Out` in IO bundles from nodes that directly belong to the corresponding `LazyModule`.

For example, if you have a sub lazy module of `XXXCrossing` which contains a node. You'd better not use its `bundleIn/Out` as your current lazy module's IO bundles. Otherwise, the chisel code might successfully get compiled but the firrtl result contains undeclared symbols.